# css selector based upon neighbour elements visibility

Tags: css

In the following structure

```
<dl>
    <dt>Text</dt>
        <dd>MoreText</dd>
    <dt>Text 2</dt>
        <dd>MoreText 2</dd>
</dl>
```

I want to gray out a text (dt) if the corresponding dd is set to display:none. I belive that there is a way to combine css selectors to achieve this, but can´t find a working solution.

Comment: No there isn't ... you cannot select the previous element using CSS

Comment: Also, there is no way CSS can decide and apply styles based on elements visibility, but if the element is empty, then yes, you can use `:empty` pseudo

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Sorry.. missinterpreted the question...

Comment: @LcSalazar eh its fine, will delete my comments as I just wanted you to retract the false vote :)

Comment: @LcSalazar Will do it for you

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "previous sibling" selector. There is an "[next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)" selector, though.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. You must use JS/JQuery for manipulating classes.
You must look on css rules like on XPath to an element, you can go only deeper, not on sides.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible in CSS as you want to do this based on a condition.

But you can use jQuery / JavaScript to achieve the same

1. By checking the status of neighbour.
2. Then getting parent of it.
3. Then selecting desired element finally.
4. Making changes to desired element.